# Fabric JS _updateObjectsCoords alternative? (Migration issue to 1.7.9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fabricjs

**Update:** JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/Qanary/915fg6ka/

I am trying to make my `curveText` function work (see bottom of this post). It normally works with `fabric.js 1.2.0` however when I updated to `fabric.js` 1.7.9, the curving function locates the text in wrong positions when below **two actions** executed **sequentially**.

**ACTIONS : - ISSUE 1**

-text group scale is changed (I mean dragging the corner points by mouse to change size).

-setText called

**fabric js 1.2.0:**

[image]

**fabric js 1.7.9**

[image]

I debugged it and the reason for that is `_updateObjectsCoords` in fabricjs because when I removed it from the code and 2 actions I listed above works fine.

**ISSUE 2:**
But this time I have faced below problem which is group items are not correctly located when adding the text to canvas for the first time.

with `_updateObjectsCoords`

[image]

without `_updateObjectsCoords`

[image]

**Here My Function:**

```
var CurvedText = (function() {

    function CurvedText( canvas, options ){
        this.opts = options || {};
        for ( var prop in CurvedText.defaults ) {
            if (prop in this.opts) { continue; }
            this.opts[prop] = CurvedText.defaults[prop];
        }

        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.group = new fabric.Group([], {selectable: this.opts.selectable,radiusVal:this.opts.radius,spacingVal:this.opts.spacing,textFliping:this.opts.reverse});
        this.canvas.add( this.group ) ;
        this.canvas.centerObject( this.group );
        this.setText( this.opts.text );
        this.canvas.setActiveObject( this.group );
        this.canvas.getActiveObject().setCoords();

    }

    CurvedText.prototype.setObj = function(obj) 
    {
        this.group=obj;
    };

    CurvedText.prototype.setText = function( newText ) {

        this.opts.top=this.group.top;
        this.opts.left=this.group.left;

        while ( newText.length !== 0 && this.group.size() > newText.length ) {
            this.group.remove( this.group.item( this.group.size()-1 ) );
        }

        for ( var i=0; i<newText.length; i++ ){
            if ( this.group.item(i) === undefined ){
                var letter = new fabric.Text(newText[i], {
                    selectable: true
                });
                this.group.add( letter );
            }
            else{
                this.group.item(i).text = newText[i];
            }
        }
        this.opts.text = newText;
        this._setFontStyles();
        this._render();
    };

    CurvedText.prototype._setFontStyles = function() {
        for ( var i=0; i<this.group.size(); i++ ){
            if( this.opts.textStyleName )
            {
                if( this.opts.textStyleName === 'fontFamily' )
                {
                    this.group.item(i).setFontFamily( this.opts.fontFamily );
                }
                if( this.opts.textStyleName === 'fontColor' )
                {
                    this.group.item(i).setFill( this.opts.fontColor );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.group.item(i).setFontFamily( this.opts.fontFamily );
                this.group.item(i).setFill( this.opts.fontColor );
            }
            this.group.item(i).setFontSize( this.opts.fontSize );
            this.group.item(i).fontWeight = this.opts.fontWeight ;
        }
    };

    CurvedText.prototype._render = function() {
        var curAngle=0,angleRadians=0, align=0;

        // Object may have been moved with drag&drop
        if ( this.group.hasMoved() ) {
            this.opts.top = this.group.top;
            this.opts.left = this.group.left;
        }
        this.opts.angle = this.group.getAngle();
        this.opts.scaleX = this.group.scaleX;
        this.opts.scaleY = this.group.scaleY;
        this.opts.radius = this.group.radiusVal;
        this.opts.spacing = this.group.spacingVal;
        this.opts.reverse = this.group.textFliping;


        // Text align
        if ( this.opts.align === 'center' ) {
            align = ( this.opts.spacing / 2) * ( this.group.size() - 1) ;
        } else if ( this.opts.align === 'right' ) {
            align = ( this.opts.spacing ) * ( this.group.size() - 1) ;
        }

        for ( var i=0; i<this.group.size(); i++) {
            // Find coords of each letters (radians : angle*(Math.PI / 180)
            if ( this.opts.reverse ) {
                curAngle = (-i * parseInt( this.opts.spacing, 10 )) + align;
                angleRadians = curAngle * (Math.PI / 180);
                this.group.item(i).setAngle( curAngle );
                this.group.item(i).set( 'top', (Math.cos( angleRadians ) * this.opts.radius) );
                this.group.item(i).set( 'left', (-Math.sin( angleRadians ) * this.opts.radius) );
            } else {
                curAngle = (i * parseInt( this.opts.spacing, 10)) - align;
                angleRadians = curAngle * (Math.PI / 180);
                this.group.item(i).setAngle( curAngle );
                this.group.item(i).set( 'top', (-Math.cos( angleRadians ) * this.opts.radius) );
                this.group.item(i).set( 'left', (Math.sin( angleRadians ) * this.opts.radius) ) ;
            }
        }

        // Update group coords
        this.group._calcBounds();
        this.group._updateObjectsCoords();
        this.group.top = this.opts.top;
        this.group.left = this.opts.left;
        this.group.saveCoords();

        this.canvas.renderAll();
    };

    CurvedText.defaults = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        angle: 0,
        spacing:0,
        radius:0,
        text: '',
        align: 'center',
        reverse:'',
        fontSize:16,
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        selectable: true,
        fontFamily:'',
        fontColor:'black',
        textStyleName:''
    };

    return CurvedText;
})();
```

Comment: I tried the JSfiddle and the example works fine, can you send a screenshot from your results taken from fiddle ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek , please try actions I mentioned sequentially. 1- Add Text, 2- Change scale of the text from the corners, 3- Click update text. The screenshots are embedded already to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @HOY I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it, if I understood you correctly:

[image: fabricjs curved text]

Just a small tweak to your `updateText()` function:

```
function updateText() {
  var original = canvas.getActiveObject();
  canvas.remove(original);
  setText();
  canvas.getActiveObject().set({
    angle: original.angle,
    top: original.top,
    left: original.left,
    scaleX: original.scaleX,
    scaleY: original.scaleY
  }).setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

And finally, here's your all important JSFiddle updated, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/pkj82n4b/.

**Update (v2)**
 - since you did plead in your bounty to make your ***function*** work, ;-).

Change this line:

```
this.group = new fabric.Group([], {selectable: this.opts.selectable,name:'arc',radiusVal:this.opts.radius,spacingVal:this.opts.spacing,textFliping:this.opts.reverse,itemName:'text'});
```

To this:

```
this.group = new fabric.Group([], {selectable: this.opts.selectable,name:'arc',radiusVal:this.opts.radius,spacingVal:this.opts.spacing,textFliping:this.opts.reverse,itemName:'text',originX:'center',originY:'center'});
```

And to get it a little more esthetically pleasing you might want to...

Change this line: `canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c',);`

To this: `canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c',{centeredScaling: true});`

And here's your original Plunker updated again, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/c7cjzkfd/.

This leaves your `updateText()` function as you had it.

Let me know if you have any other questions.  Always happy to help!

Comment: Hi Tim, you got my question right, and corrected the function with a tweak. I appreciate and it was helpful really. But my curvedText function was more detailed and other functionalities like change color, change spacing, still corrupts the group locations as above. So I am trying to use your tweak for other functions as well but having difficulties. I will let you know with details after working a little bit. Full functionality is hard to be implemented on jsfiddle. Btw, on you second jsfiddle, when a new text added, there is problem with updates.

Comment: No worries, I understand.  It can be tricky at times to get a JSFiddle that illustrates the problem - and while you're doing it one can end up fixing the problem :-).  Just update your question when you have something more.  Not sure what issue you're referring to with the second JSFiddle, short of a `.setCoords()` I noticed that needed adding (I've updated the JSFiddle).  Here's a change log for FabricJS, not sure it goes back far enough though... [http://fabricjs.com/fabric-changelog](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-changelog).

Comment: Let me know if I can be of anymore help?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have solved issues with your solution, I did not want the give bounty right away, because it could prevent other answers, and I wondered if there are other solutions as well. But I was going to give bounty to you anyway. :)

Comment: I totally understand.  Just wasn't sure how things were going since I hadn't heard from you.  Glad you're progressing nicely.  I'm actually running version 1.2 on this pre-production site, [http://xpressclocks.azurewebsites.net/create](http://xpressclocks.azurewebsites.net/create), and did start at one point looking at upgrading - hence my experience.  If my partner and I ever take it live (and it becomes somewhat profitable) I'll be heading down a similar road to you :-)!!!  Do let me know if you have other questions as you continue, always happy to help - we are now linked in, matey!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText you can see the demo

Comment: Hi Sofiane, I used it but faced another problem and opened an issue on github, the owner did not response and there were no good feedback. So it did not help. Here you may check: https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText/issues/37